# VBA code _ Update one Pivot Item in a field within several pivot table

Tags: vba, xls

I am woking on Year to date basis, so forprevious year, I am updating the weeks selected (From week 1 to current week (see below) table by table.
Is there a way to update in the same way other pivot table in the same sheet but not them all or should y just pate the action below for each table.

```
Dim Pi As PivotItem
Dim Pf As PivotFields
Dim Pt As PivotTable

Set Pt = Sheets("FarmSheetPivot"). PivotTables("Farm_2012")
    With Pt.PivotFields("ReportWk")

For Each Pi In .PivotItems
If (Pi.Value) <= Range("b1") Then
                            Pi.Visible = True
                            Else
                            Pi.Visible = False
    End If
Next
End With

End Sub
```

Tks a lot